# Automatic Refetch with invalidatesTags

Tags: rtk-query

I am using RTK Query for my app's API requests. So far everything is working smoothly! I have followed the documentation in regards to providing tags and invalidating them but I am facing a weird behaviour. Following is the code of two related endpoints:

```
export const api = createApi({
    /*** code omitted for brevity ***/

    tagTypes: ["Post"],
    endpoints: (builder) => ({
        getPost: builder.query({
            query: (id) => ({
                url: `posts/${id}`,
                method: "GET",
            }),
            providesTags: (result, error, id) => [{ type: "Post", id }],
        }),
        bookmarkPost: builder.mutation({
            query: (id) => ({
                url: `posts/bookmark/${id}`,
                method: "POST",
            }),
            invalidatesTags: (result, error, id) => [{ type: "Post", id }],
        }),
    }),
});
```

Now fetching data is working perfectly fine. However, when the `bookmarkPost` request is successful the tagged `getPost` does not automatically refetch.

The tagged `getPost` only works if I manually set the `id` property. For example `[{ type: "Post", id: "TOPIC" }]`. Or, if I target the tag as a whole `["Post"]`

The `id` part in my database is a `Guid` so I suspected this might be an issue (giving that the documentation states that the `id` should be a string or a number) and I normalized it to a string without dashes. But even doing so did not trigger invalidations.

Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 0):

After pulling some hair, I realized that the string case in `providesTags` (uppercase) did not match the string case in `invalidatesTags` (lowercase). The `Guid` is converted to a string anyway ‍♂️